# javascript not working after jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am developing my first mobile web app using jquery,

When i press a button to go to the next page it does but the javascript on the page doesnt work.

Here is my code , As before my header is a php doc so i dont have to recall all the time
header.php

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<!--<html>-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Balti Tandoori</title>

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="iphone.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup.png" />
<!--<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />-->



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
            <!-- App custom styles -->



     <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/balti.min.css" />
     <link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> 

            <style type="text/css" media="screen">



        h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .drawers-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;

        }

        .drawer {
        background-color:#ffffff;

            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:20px;
            line-height:1.3em;

        }
<!-- NO REQUIRED -->
        .boxcap {
            height:5px;
            left:0pt;
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            z-index:100;
            background:transparent url(http://images.apple.com/downloads/images/sidenav_capbottom.png) no-repeat scroll 0%;
            margin-top:-5px;
        }

        .captop {
            background-image:url(http://images.apple.com/downloads/images/box_188captop.png );
            bottom:auto;
            top:0pt;
            margin-top:0;
        }
<!-- END JUST DOES CORNERS -->
        .drawers {
            margin-bottom:15px;
            color:#76797C;
            font-size:11px;
            line-height: 18px;

        }

        .drawers A {
            color:#666666;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family:"Lucida Grande",Geneva,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size-adjust:none;
            font-style:normal;
            font-variant:normal;
            font-weight:normal;
        }

        .drawer li {
            border-bottom:1px solid #E5E5E5;
            line-height:16px;
            padding:6px 0pt;
        }

        UL {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        UL.drawers {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .drawer-handle {
            background-color:#000000;

            color:#ffffff;
            cursor:default;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:normal;
            height:50px;
            line-height:25px;
            margin-bottom:0pt;
            text-indent:15px;
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid #ffffff
        }

        .drawer-handle.open {
        background:transparent url(css/body.gif) no-repeat;


        }

        .drawer UL {
            padding: 0 12px;
            padding-bottom:0pt;
        }

        .drawer-content UL {
            padding-top: 7px;
        }

        .drawer-content LI A {
            display:block;
            overflow:hidden;

        }

        .alldownloads li {
            border:0pt none;
            line-height:18px;
            padding:0pt;

        }

        </style>




        <script src="jquery.dimensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  






    <!-- link to allow bookmark website -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bookmark/add2home.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var addToHomeConfig = {
        animationIn: 'bubble',
        animationOut: 'drop',
        lifespan:10000,
        expire:2,
        touchIcon:true,
        message:'Add Our Mobile App To Your <strong>%device</strong> Home Page. Available Anytime `%icon`.'
        };
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="bookmark/add2home.js"></script>
    <!-- bookmark end -->

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
        });    
    </script>  
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  $('UL.drawers').accordion({
    // the drawer handle
    header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

    // our selected class
    selectedClass: 'open',

    // match the Apple slide out effect
    event: 'mouseover'
  });
});

</script>


    </head>
```

this is my index.php

```
<?
require_once("header.php");
?>
<!-- do not touch above -->
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="f">
            <div data-theme="f" data-role="header">
                <img src="css/logo.gif"width="100%" style="border-bottom :1px solid white" alt="" />
            </div>
         <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-theme="b">
                        <a href="menu.php" data-transition="flip">
                            Menu
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="b">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="flip">
                            Opening Times
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="b">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="flip">
                            How To Find Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="pop" href="page1" data-theme="b" data-icon="tel" data-iconpos="left">
                    Call Us
                </a>
         <!--   </div>-->


    </div>

            <!-- do not touch below -->

            <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer">
                <h3>
                    &copy; Balti Tandoori
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the page the index calls where the javascript does not run, It will run if i disable the ajax call from the button like this But i want the ajax to work as well, How do i recall the javascript on load etc

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href='menu.php'"  data-ajax='false'
```

menu.php

```
<?
require_once("header.php");
?>
<!-- do not touch above -->
    <body>



        <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="f">
            <div data-theme="f" data-role="header">
                <img src="css/logo.gif"width="100%" style="border-bottom :1px solid white" alt="" />
            </div>
         <div data-role="content">
         <a href="index.php"  data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back" data-theme="b">Back</a>
                              <a data-role="button" data-transition="pop" href="page1" data-theme="b" data-icon="tel" data-iconpos="left">
                    Call Us
                </a>
         <!--   </div>-->


                          <div class="drawers-wrapper">
    <!--<div class="boxcap captop"></div>-->
    <ul class="drawers">

 <ul class="drawers">
        <li class="drawer">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle open">Starters</h2>
     <!-- removes under border-->
           <!-- <ul class="alldownloads">-->
            <!--removed above -->
            <ul>
                <li id="sn-downloadsmacosx">All Categories <div style="text-align:right;">£2.50</div></li>
                <li id="sn-aperture">Big dish<div style="text-align:right;">£2.50</div></li>
                <li id="sn-apple"><a href="/downloads/macosx/apple/">Apple</a></li>

                <li id="sn-video"><a href="/downloads/macosx/video/">Video</a></li>
                <li id="sn-dashboard"><a href="/downloads/dashboard/" class="bottom">Widgets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drawer">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle">Tandoori</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="iTunes 7.5" href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/">1. iTunes 7.5</a></li>
                <li><a title="QuickTime 7.3.1" href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">2. QuickTime 7.3.1</a></li>

                <li><a title="iSquint" href="/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/isquint.html">13. iSquint</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="US Holiday Calendar" href="/downloads/macosx/calendars/usholidaycalendar.html">14. US Holiday Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li class="drawer">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle">Traditional</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="iTunes 7.5" href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/">1. iTunes 7.5</a></li>
                <li><a title="QuickTime 7.3.1" href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">2. QuickTime 7.3.1</a></li>

                <li><a title="iSquint" href="/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/isquint.html">13. iSquint</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="US Holiday Calendar" href="/downloads/macosx/calendars/usholidaycalendar.html">14. US Holiday Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li class="drawer">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle">Originals</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="iTunes 7.5" href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/">1. iTunes 7.5</a></li>
                <li><a title="QuickTime 7.3.1" href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">2. QuickTime 7.3.1</a></li>

                <li><a title="iSquint" href="/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/isquint.html">13. iSquint</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="US Holiday Calendar" href="/downloads/macosx/calendars/usholidaycalendar.html">14. US Holiday Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li class="drawer">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle">Specials</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="iTunes 7.5" href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/">1. iTunes 7.5</a></li>
                <li><a title="QuickTime 7.3.1" href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">2. QuickTime 7.3.1</a></li>

                <li><a title="iSquint" href="/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/isquint.html">13. iSquint</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="US Holiday Calendar" href="/downloads/macosx/calendars/usholidaycalendar.html">14. US Holiday Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drawer last">
            <h2 class="drawer-handle">Fish</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a title="iTunes 7.5" href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/">1. iTunes 7.5</a></li>
                <li><a title="QuickTime 7.3.1" href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">2. QuickTime 7.3.1</a></li>

                <li><a title="Security Update 2007-009 1.1 (10.4.11 Universal)" href="/downloads/macosx/apple/security_updates/securityupdate20070091110411universal.html">13. Security Update 20</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a title="Security Update 2007-009 1.1 (10.5.1)" href="/downloads/macosx/apple/security_updates/securityupdate2007009111051.html">14. Security Update 20</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
<!--<div class="boxcap"></div>-->
    </div>  



            </div>      



            <!-- do not touch below -->
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer">
                <h3>
                    &copy; Balti Tandoori
                </h3>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for your help

added for clarity to header.php

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).bind('pageinit', function(){  //new bit added in script
$(function () {
  $('UL.drawers').accordion({
    // the drawer handle
    header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

    // our selected class
    selectedClass: 'open',

    // match the Apple slide out effect
    event: 'mouseover'
  });
});
});          //new bit added in script
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Which* JavaScript isn't working?  I'm having a hard time getting exactly what it is that you mean, but I'm willing to take a hunch that none of your event handlers are getting bound.  You don't show what the contents of all those external script files contain, so I can't say that for sure, but just a quick breakdown:

All of your JavaScript tags are in the head of your document.  That means that they get loaded up before the body tag has been processed.  Additionally, jQuery Mobile creates a great deal of the DOM dynamically.  Nowhere do I see a call to `$(document).ready()`, which is fine because this has been sort of "phased out" in jQuery Mobile, **nor** do I see a call to `$(document).bind("pageinit", function())`, which is the preferred way to bind event handlers to DOM elements after the page has loaded in jQuery Mobile.

I see you bind a callback to the document's `mobileinit` event, but [per the jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) documentation, this is called long before the DOM is built up.

Let's say that your accordion function is what isn't working.  The pattern you're looking for is something like:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    $('UL.drawers').accordion({
    // the drawer handle
    header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

    // our selected class
    selectedClass: 'open',

    // match the Apple slide out effect
    event: 'mouseover'
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, yes it is the accordian function which is not working. Not to sound stupid but where would i put the code u have written above.

Comment: If you wanted, you could add that code to your existing script tag where you bind to mobileinit.  The snippet should appear somewhere on every page.

Comment: so for my script in the header in theory it should look like the extra i have added above

Comment: See my edit above, you don't need to double up on the function declarations like that.

Comment: thanks for your help Doug, the slider doesnt work anymore but ill still play around with it. Again thanks for taking time to help